# How to create a nested json from a json and replace the different key values with single key

Tags: python, json, pandas, dataframe

I have a json like this (this is formed by converting a pandas data frame to json):

```
"columns0": {
    "0": 9100,
    "4": 8550,
    "9": 0,
    "11": 1.5,
    "12": 35000,
    "13": 0
},
"columns1": {
    "0": 5000,
    "4": 38317.7,
    "9": 423,
    "11": 19.14,
    "12": 35000,
    "13": 320
}
```

I want to modify this json which will be a nested json where the keys will be unique for each nested json. The output json should look like this:

```
"columns0": {
    {"key1": 9100},
    {"key1": 8550},
    {"key1": 0},
    {"key1": 1.5},
    {"key1": 35000},
    {"key1": 0}
},
"columns1": {
    {"key1": 5000},
    {"key1": 38317.7},
    {"key1": 423},
    {"key1": 19.14},
    {"key1": 35000},
    {"key1": 320}
}
```

How to do it using python ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Python doesn't allow to create a dictionary without key and value pair as you mention in an expected output of new json.

```
jsonData = { "columns0": {
            "0": 9100,
            "4": 8550,
            "9": 0,
            "11": 1.5,
            "12": 35000,
            "13": 0
        },
        "columns1": {
            "0": 5000,
            "4": 38317.7,
            "9": 423,
            "11": 19.14,
            "12": 35000,
            "13": 320
        }
    }

new_json = {}
for key in jsonData:
    sub_list = []
    for neste_key in jsonData[key]:
        sub_json = dict(key1=jsonData[key][neste_key])
        sub_list.append(sub_json)

    if len(sub_list) > 0:
        new_json[key] = sub_list

print(new_json)
```

**O/P:**

```
{
  'columns0': [
    {'key1': 9100},
    {'key1': 8550},
    {'key1': 0},
    {'key1': 1.5},
    {'key1': 35000},
    {'key1': 0}
  ],
  'columns1': [
    {'key1': 5000},
    {'key1': 38317.7},
    {'key1': 423},
    {'key1': 19.14},
    {'key1': 35000},
    {'key1': 320}
  ]
}
```

Comment: I haven't ask to create duplicate key, my expected output is to create a nested json which will be having keys. just check my expected out again.

Answer (score 0):

Your expected output is not a valid json nor dict.

```
"columns0": {
    {"key1": 9100},
    {"key1": 8550},
    {"key1": 0},
    {"key1": 1.5},
    {"key1": 35000},
    {"key1": 0}
}
```

Maybe you meant an array of objects?

```
"columns0": [
    {"key1": 9100},
    {"key1": 8550},
    {"key1": 0},
    {"key1": 1.5},
    {"key1": 35000},
    {"key1": 0}
]
```

If so, this code should work:

```
old_dict = {
    "columns0": {
        "0": 9100,
        "4": 8550,
        "9": 0,
        "11": 1.5,
        "12": 35000,
        "13": 0
    },
    "columns1": {
        "0": 5000,
        "4": 38317.7,
        "9": 423,
        "11": 19.14,
        "12": 35000,
        "13": 320
    }
}

new_dict = {}

for c_name, c_values in old_dict.items():
    new_dict[c_name] = [{"key1": v } for v in c_values.values()]
```

Answer (score 0):

This it what you want, I guess.

```
    new_json={}
    for i in range(0,2):
        s="columns"+str(i)
        l = []
        for v in j[s].values():
            t={}
            t["key1"]=v
            l.append(t)
        new_json[s]=l
```

`new_json` look like this:

```
   {'columns0': 
    [{'key1': 9100}, 
    {'key1': 8550}, 
    {'key1': 0}, 
    {'key1': 1.5}, 
    {'key1': 35000}, 
    {'key1': 0}], 
    'columns1': 
    [{'key1': 5000}, 
    {'key1': 38317.7}, 
    {'key1': 423}, 
    {'key1': 19.14}, 
    {'key1': 35000}, 
    {'key1': 320}]
}
```